# calculate the complexity of an algorithm using Back Substitution

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I have the function :

```
int ps (int n) 
{ if (n == 1) return 1; 
 else return (Extra(n) + Ps (n/4) + Ps (n/4)); }
```

Extra(n) is O(n)

I have tried to find T(n) of this function which is T(n)=T(n)+2 T(n/4) and I have calculated the complexity using the master theorem it is O(n)
but I don't know how to find the complexity of it using back substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are wrong in terms of complexity. You didn't mention `Extra(n)` in writing the time complexity. So, `T(n) = 2 T(n/4) + n`. Now, I think the new recurrent complexity term is easy to solve by substitution:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/4) + n = 2 (2 T(n/8) + n/4) + n = 2^2 T(n/8) + n/2 + n =
2^2 (2 T(n/16) + n/8) + n/2 + n = 2^3 T(n/16) + n/4 + n/2 + n
```

Now, by mathematical induction, if we suppose `n = 2^k`, you can find that:

```
T(n) = n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... + n/2^k = n (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/2^k) <= 2n
```

The last part of the above analysis comes from the being geometric series of the sum with factor `1/2`. Hence, `T(n)` is in `Theta(n)` and `O(n)`.